# Does matlab have a ternary operator?

Tags: matlab

I would like to use a C-like ternary operator but in Matlab, how can this be done?

For example:

```
a = (test == 'yes') ? c : d
```

where a,c and d are numeric but in Matlab?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A couple of options:

**Inline if statement**

```
a = (test == 'yes') * c;
```

**Inline if else statement**

```
a = (test == 'yes') * c + (test ~= 'yes') * d;
```

or more neatly:

```
t = test == 'yes'; a = t * c + ~t * d;
```

This works in the numeric case since `test == 'yes'` is cast to 0 or 1 depending on whether it's true or not - which can then be multiplied by the desired outcomes (if they are numeric).

Comment: While this is not quite the same thing, it is close enough and should get the job done. And did you answer your own question within a minute of posting.

Comment: @MZimmerman6 Yes, it did the job for me. I just wanted to share it because I thought it was quite good at the time :)

Comment: This will fail if any of values of t is NaN or +/-Inf.

Answer (score 7):

To provide an alternative:

```
t = xor([false true], isequal(test, 'yes')) * [c; d]
```

or if you want

```
ternary = @(condition, trueValue, falseValue)...
    xor([false true], condition) * [trueValue; falseValue];

...

t = ternary(isequal(test, 'yes'), c, d);
```